# PHP Check if Many spaces before or after a string

Tags: php

On my website, after a user registers they can change their username at any time. The minimum amount of characters is 6 and max amount is 25.

Here's some of the coding to check the length and remove characters:

```
$users_new_name = strip_tags($_POST['new_name']);
$new_name = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z -]/", "", $users_new_name);
// Check Length
if (ctype_space($new_name)) {
$message = die('<span class="Fail">Error: Name Must Be At least 6 Characters Long!</i></span>');    
}
if(strlen($new_name) < 6) {
$message = die('<span class="Fail">Error: Name Must Be At least 6 Characters Long!</i></span>');
}
if(strlen($new_name) > 25) {
$message = die('<span class="Fail">Error: Name Can\'t Be More Than 25 Characters Long!</i></span>');
}
```

The issue I'm having is if you type in 5 spaces and then a letter or number, There new name will be that letter or number; Or if you type in a letter or number then 5 spaces. How could I prevent this from happening?

Here's a screenshot of the example[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why tags would be in a POST.

Spaces becomes a non-issue if you change:

```
$users_new_name = strip_tags($_POST['new_name']);
```

To

```
$users_new_name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['new_name']));
```

Or ideally (strip tags is unnecessary):

```
$users_new_name = trim($_POST['new_name']);
```

Change the RegEx expression to `/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/` to eliminate spaces and dashes.

Comment: @user3059258 this only removes spaces from the front and back

Comment: @Misunderstood That's what I needed was from the front and the back, The trim Worked Perfectly!

Comment: The problem was also in the RegEx.  It was saying spaces were allowed.  [^ ] or [^x20] say to allow spaces.  By removing the space dash. spaces and dashes would then be eliminated.  /[^0-9a-zA-Z|x20|x2D]/ would have worked too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need `trim()` to trim any spaces from the username. See http://php.net/trim

`ltrim()` will trim any leading spaces. `rtrim()` will trim any spaces at the end of the string.

Comment: That Worked Perfectly! But also, on the preg_replace Dashes aren't being removed, Not sure why!

Comment: @user3059258 In that case I would adjust the `preg_replace`, or do a simple `str_replace` on the username to remove dashes.

Comment: @user3059258 it'd because you added `-` at the end of the character block. For alphanumeric use `"/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/"`

Comment: To simply allow alphanumeric, copy the regex in @kdogisthebest's comment.

Comment: I changed it to: 
`$new_name = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/", "", $users_new_name);
$new_name .= preg_replace('-', '', $users_new_name);`

Works Fine now

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple and it's something I've had to deal with on systems before.

If you make the first thing you call, this preg_replace, the rest of you code should catch it;

```
$name = preg_replace('~[\s]+~', '', $name);
```

This simply checks if there is a space, or more than one, then replaces with a single space.

So "     l" would return " l" - failing your 5 character minimum.

Use trim() around this and you should have it working to something acceptable (Depending on your definition of acceptable - worked in my use-case)